# Flow JS - How to use Generics in an Object as a Map with a Class

Tags: flowtype

I have the following class:

```
// @flow

type Entities<EntityType> = {
    [number]: EntityType
}

export default class NormalizedCollection<EntityType> {
    entities: Entities<EntityType>
    result: Array<number>

    constructor(entities: Entities<EntityType>, result: Array<number>) {
        this.entities = entities
        this.result = result
    }

    getItems = (): Array<Object> => {
        try {
            if (this.result) {
                return this.result.map((index, key) => this.entities[index]).filter((item)=>typeof item !== 'undefined')
            }
        } catch (e) {}

        return []
    }

    find = (id: number): Entities<EntityType> | null =>  {
        if(typeof this.entities === 'undefined' || typeof this.entities[id] === 'undefined') {
            return null
        }
        return this.entities[id]
    }
}
```

This class takes two parameters, Entities (an Object which functions as a Map) and Results which is an Array of numbers. I'd like consumers of the class to be able to indicate the entity type they are passing.

This gives me two errors.

From getItems:

`Cannot return this.result.map(...).filter(...) because EntityType [1] is incompatible with object type [2] in array element.`

From find:

`Cannot return this.entities[id] because EntityType [1] is incompatible with Entities [2]`

What is the proper way to pass the entity type to NormalizedCollection?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to change the return types! (`Array<EntityType>` and `EntityType` respectively).

```
// @flow

type Entities<EntityType> = {
    [id: number]: EntityType
}

export default class NormalizedCollection<EntityType> {
    entities: Entities<EntityType>
    result: Array<number>

    constructor(entities: Entities<EntityType>, result: Array<number>) {
        this.entities = entities
        this.result = result
    }

    getItems = (): Array<EntityType> => {
        try {
            if (this.result) {
                return this.result.map(index => this.entities[index]).filter((item)=>typeof item !== 'undefined')
            }
        } catch (e) {}

        return []
    }

    find = (id: number): EntityType | null =>  {
        if(typeof this.entities === 'undefined' || typeof this.entities[id] === 'undefined') {
            return null
        }
        return this.entities[id]
    }
}
```